# how to connect to multiple-server- machine in GSS?

Tags: c, kerberos, gssapi

There some machines:
client C1, server : master, s1, s2

C1 connect to master and do the authentication, then the job runner was created at s1 and s2, C1 and s1, s2 need security communication. how to do this through Kerberos/GSS-API. master , s1 and s2 are security connected.

Thanks

Dma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Request the GSSAPI to [encrypt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/security/jgss/tutorials/BasicClientServer.html#ExchangeMsgs) your communication. I use this with SASL and Active Directory. All traffic is securely wrapped.